# Check if users are a member of an AD group - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i have a txt file with a list of usernames and I want to check if these users are a member of a specific AD-group. If they aren't a member of this group, their username has to be written in a csv file. So the output should be a csv file with all usernames who are not in the specified AD-group.

I always get the error "A connection to the directory on which to process the request was unavailable. This is likely a transient condition".The error is reproduced when implementing a workflow that triggers up to 20 powershell sessions to run, each importing the Active Directory module to create a connection with AD.

This is my short script:

```
 $userlist = get-content -Path "C:\Temp\users.txt"

 $group = "group_xy"


 $result = foreach ($user in $userlist)
 {
     $groupmembers = Get-ADgroup -Filter {Name -eq $group}|Get-ADGroupMember 

     if ($groupmembers.samaccountname -notmatch $users){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $user 
        Group = $group 
        Member = 'False'
        }
    }
    
}

$result |Export-csv "C:\Temp\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

How can I solve this?

BR

Comment: Create a variable which contains all users of your group outside of the foreach loop. So you have only one AD call. Then you can check if the user is in the variable with all users of the group

Comment: I don't get it.  I cannot get all users because the list of the members of the AD-group is too long

Comment: Do you really need to use a `workflow` for something like this ? If the answer is yes, then you know what you need to do to avoid the error.

Comment: Use `Get-ADUser ` with LDAPFilter for the group. I think this command should not have the limition of the `Get-ADgroup` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($groupmembers.samaccountname -notmatch $users) {
```

Should be

```
if ($groupmembers.samaccountname -notmatch $user) {
```

Since you never define `$users` I think this is the error

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I didn't make this mistake in my script